# Control number of records processed by a mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to control the number of records processed by each mapper.

In my cluster some data nodes have more number of records. So the mappers created at that nodes process more no. of records. So these mappers running for long duration.

Mapper processing time does not depend on my record size. Number of records decide the time. So is there any way to control the number of records  processed by each mapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can supply -**D mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=some number**. You can arrive at this number by knowing how many records each mapper should process and what would be there size.

Comment: problem is each record size vary drastically. So the same issue will occur if I pass spit size.

Comment: Assume you have 1,00,000 records equivalent to 64MB and it takes 20 minutes to process. So if you use the split size as 32 MB, you will have 2 mappers running in parallel. So it would take 10 mins to process the same no of records.

Comment: Each record size is not same. Only the record processing time is same. In 32MB there can be only 25,000 records(5 mins) and the other 75,000(15 mins) will reside in the another 32MB. So I cannot split the records by size.

Comment: Then use NLineInputFormat where N is the fixed lines to be processed.